# How to split up log file with awk or sed. Replacement for python script

Tags: python, awk, sed

Lets assume you have an instrument log file for each single day. During the day several reboots may happen. For some reason you want to have a file per reboot.

Finally I used python to do it but I would like to do the same with awk or sed.
Please let me know your ideas.

python script split_instrument_log.py

```
def split_instrument_log(filename):
    first_line = '--- ServiceHost Start ---'
    count = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
        text = handle.read()
        split_text = text.split('\n' + first_line)
        for split in split_text:
            split_file_name = filename + "." + str(count)
            with open(split_file_name, 'w') as split_handle:
                if count > 0:
                    split_handle.write(first_line)
                split_handle.write(split)
            count = count + 1

filename = "instrument.log";
split_instrument_log(filename)
```

example instrument.log:

```
--- ServiceHost Start ---
11:43:54.745 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 11:43:54 AM
...
--- ServiceHost Start ---
14:47:37.071 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 2:47:37 PM
...
--- ServiceHost Start ---
18:27:57.463 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 6:27:57 PM
...
```

result instrument.log.0

```
--- ServiceHost Start ---
11:43:54.745 00000001 HOST       I  Creating System 2/19/2018 11:43:54 AM
...
```

I have another log which starts with a timestamp and an address in it e.g.

```
[05/02/2018 13:32:30.160 UTC] Main Thread (0xb4692000)/ 0 INF socMainExecutable
```

How update the awk script, but note that timestamp and address are not constant ?

Comment: Any reason you want to replace a working script with a script in a different language? Are you trying to teach yourself awk, or is there a performance problem, or do you have servers without Python installed, or…?

Comment: I am interested in a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` it is quite direct:

**INPUT:**

```
$ more instrument.log
--- ServiceHost Start ---
11:43:54.745 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 11:43:54 AM
blabla1
blabla2
blabla3
...
--- ServiceHost Start ---
14:47:37.071 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 2:47:37 PM
...
blabla4
blabla5
blabla6
--- ServiceHost Start ---
18:27:57.463 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 6:27:57 PM
...
blabla7
blabla8
blabla9
```

**awk script:**

```
awk -v i=-1 '/--- ServiceHost Start ---/{i++; print $0 > "instrument.log."i; next}{print $0 >> "instrument.log."i}' instrument.log
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ more instrument.log.?
::::::::::::::
instrument.log.0
::::::::::::::
--- ServiceHost Start ---
11:43:54.745 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 11:43:54 AM
blabla1
blabla2
blabla3
...
::::::::::::::
instrument.log.1
::::::::::::::
--- ServiceHost Start ---
14:47:37.071 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 2:47:37 PM
...
blabla4
blabla5
blabla6
::::::::::::::
instrument.log.2
::::::::::::::
--- ServiceHost Start ---
18:27:57.463 00000001 HOST I  Creating System 2/19/2018 6:27:57 PM
...
blabla7
blabla8
blabla9
```

**Explanation:**

- `-v i=-1` pass a variable `i` to `awk` with initial value at `-1`, you can also define it in a BEGIN clause like this: `BEGIN{i=-1}`.
- `/--- ServiceHost Start ---/{i++; print $0 > "instrument.log."i; next}` whenever `awk` finds a line containing `--- ServiceHost Start ---` it will increment `i` and will print the line content to a file `"instrument.log."i` before going to next line. (it will overwrite the file if it exists)
- `{print $0 >> "instrument.log."i}` for other lines just append to the file `"instrument.log."i`

Comment: I have another log which starts with a timestamp and an address in it e.g. [05/02/2018 13:32:30.160 UTC] Main Thread         (0xb4692000)/   0 INF socMainExecutable. How update the awk script ?

Comment: Could you add it to this question or make a new question I will have a look as soon as I can :)